# Mac Terminal find current folder with name like 'xxx' with find command

Tags: unix, find

Is there a way to find folders with name matching. The following is what I have tried. I want to filter out any folder names that start with **react** .

```
find ./ -type d -name "react*"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have got my college to help me out on this one.

```
find * -maxdepth 0 | grep name_of_your_folder
```